# python 3 fabric 2 returning control characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

I am using python 3 and fabric 2 library from a Windows Server 2019 to access Azure remote Linux server (3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64, LANG=en_US.UTF-8).

Doing a remote copy from fstab, I get no return and specials characters are displayed at the start and the end of the command if I turn the echo on.

```
def _map_folder_remotely(connection,fstab_entry):
    print("Mapping folder remotely...")
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")
    command = f"sudo cp -v /etc/fstab /home/azureuser/fstab.{now}"
    result = connection.run(command=command, hide=False, echo=True)
    if not result.ok:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Command {command} failed")
    print(result.stdout)
```

I get on screen:

```
Mapping folder remotely...
sudo cp -v /etc/fstab /home/azureuser/fstab.20201126144809557390
â€˜/etc/fstabâ€™ -> â€˜/home/azureuser/fstab.20201126144809557390â€™
```

and the fstab file is not copied
Any idea about the problem? What wrong?